# FullSimplify completely changes result

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerics

I have a function that when I operate `FullSimplify` on, produces widly different results depending on if the parameters are left symbolic or values are substituted in before the simplification. I've narrowed down the part of my function that `FullSimplify` messes up.:

```
func = E^(-((-(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^
     p + \[Rho])^2/\[Sigma])) + E^(-(((x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^
    p + \[Rho])^2/\[Sigma]))
```

This is just two gaussians translated symmetrically about the origin. Now, If I do `FullSimplify` on this function, I get the expected result which is that basically nothing happens. The function is already pretty simple. But if I input some parameter values:

```
E^(-33.3333 (0.8 - (x^2 + y^2 + 
      z^2)^0.26)^2) + E^(-33.3333 (0.8 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^0.26)^2)
```

Then pass `FullSimplify` to this, Mathematica reduces it to zero.

```
FullSimplify[E^(-33.3333 (0.8 - (x^2 + y^2 + 
      z^2)^0.26)^2) + E^(-33.3333 (0.8 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^0.26)^2)]

---> (*0.*)
```

This is really strange and almost introduced mistakes into my research since I didnt catch it at first. Luckily, I did some consistency checks and analysis and found the mistake. Unfortunately, the functions I work with are really large, so I would like to use simplification early on in the code so that it reduces computation time later.

Is there a way I can still use simplification without Mathematica killing the result? I see there have been some other issues with FullSimplify, but I think this one is unique enough to warrant a separate question, given the use of Exponentials.

I appreciate any insight and help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Floats cause that. The `Rationalize` command helps.

```
FullSimplify[Rationalize[E^(-33.3333 (0.8 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^0.26)^2) + 
E^(-33.3333 (0.8 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^0.26)^2), 10^-40]]
```

> `E^(-((333333 (4 - 5 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(13/50))^2)/250000)) + E^(-(( 333333 (4/5 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(13/50))^2)/10000))`

Addition. Maybe, the result of

```
FullSimplify[E^Expand@Rationalize[(-33.3333 (0.8 - (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^0.26)^2), 
 10^-40] +  E^Expand@Rationalize[(-33.3333 (0.8 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^0.26)^2), 
 10^-40], Assumptions -> {x, y, z} \[Element] Reals]
```

> `E^(-((333333 (4 + 5 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(13/50))^2)/ 250000)) (1 + E^((333333 (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(13/50))/3125))`

is more preferable.

Comment: Thanks! yea I figured it was floating point errors coming in. I was just surprised how much the simplification changed the result so I thought it could be something else. I already changed my code to wait until the last minute to input parameter values and that fixed it.

Answer (score 5):

Try first to simplify, then to substitute:

```
Simplify[func, {\[Rho] > 0, p > 0, \[Sigma] > 0}] /. {\[Sigma] -> 3./
   100, p -> 0.26, \[Rho] -> 0.8}

(* E^(-33.3333 (-0.8 + (x^2 + y^2 + 
      z^2)^0.26)^2) + E^(-33.3333 (0.8 + (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^0.26)^2)  *)
```

Have fun!